# Нет вывода в xlsx

Tags: python, xlsx

суть такова что нужно получить данные из канала и записать из файл

```
import youtube_dl
import pandas as pd

ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors': True, 'quiet': True}

channel_id = '@glamgosquad3961'
shorts_url = f'https://www.youtube.com/{channel_id}/shorts'
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    channel_info = ydl.extract_info(shorts_url, download=False)
    print(channel_info)

shorts = channel_info['entries']
rows = []
for short in shorts:
    row = {
        'URL': short['webpage_url'],
        'Дата выхода': short['upload_date'],
        'Количество просмотров': short['view_count']
    }
    if 'tags' in short and 'music' in short['tags']:
        row['Мелодия'] = short['tags']['music']
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.to_excel('shorts.xlsx', index=False)
```

ничего не сохраняется в файл shorts.xlsx

Comment: Он есть, создается, но в нем ничего нет

Comment: Здесь дело не выводе, а в том, что плейлист скачивается пустой

Comment: Можете помочь исправить это пожалуйста?